# opener.document is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Buenos Días.

Tengo esto en formulario b:

```
 function ue_aceptar_reportedesde()
{
    opener.document.formulario.cmbcodtipsol2.value="";
    opener.document.formulario.cmbcodtipsol2.disabled=true;
    close();
}
```

El cmbcodtipsol2 es el id de un select de otro formulario A. Hay una manera de decirle que el cmbcodtipsol2 pertenece aL formulario a ya que por eso me da el error undefined.

No se si me logre explicar, disculpa si no logre hacerlo soy nuevo en este mundo.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué es `opener`?

Comment: entiendo que abre otro formulario e interactuas con los elementos de ese formulario

Comment: Eso es una propiedad de `window.open()` y lo que pusiste código no se ve dónde estés mandando llamar esa función, por lo que una razón del error es precisamente que no estás mandando llamar la función https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

Comment: esa funcion la llamo cuando seleccion un codigo unico de un presupuesto a  traves de un resultado de una busqueda determinada